# Import and use openGL GLUQuadric?

Tags: c#, windows, opengl

I'm trying to use some native functions in C# over OpenGL.
I need to draw a Sphere and I read about gluSphere and looked at it on GL\glu.h, but receives a struct object as parameter:

```
typedef struct GLUquadric GLUquadric;

void APIENTRY gluSphere(GLUquadric *qobj,GLdouble radius,GLint slices,GLint stacks);
```

I need to create a struct so I can send it to `gluSphere`.
Is there some place or information of how is `GLUquadric` defined so I can write it and send it to `gluSphere` ?

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct GLUquadric{
          //What's here???
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like searching in google for

> "struct GLUquadric"

didn't give any information or clue... But searching for

> "struct GLUquadric{ "

took me to the place I wanted:

[OGLES_GLU.h](http://nguyen.univ-tln.fr/share/OpenGL/ogles_glu.h)

Struct I found and used and WORKS is:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct GLUquadric
        {
            int normals;
            bool textureCoords;
            int orientation;
            int drawStyle;
        }
```

So now I can use:

```
[DllImport("glu32.dll")]
static extern void gluSphere(ref GLUquadric qobj, double radius, int slices, int stacks);
        public static void Sphere(ref GLUquadric qobject, double Radius, int Slices, int Stacks)
        {
            gluSphere(ref qobject, Radius, Slices, Stacks);
        }
```

OpenGL draws spheres now.

NOTE: When drawing spheres in imported openGL function, DO NOT CALL `gluDeleteQuadric();`
Let GC do it's work, just declare a new `GLUQuadric()` and send it as a `ref` to `gluSphere`, else you will have memory problems in your program.

To compliment datenwolf's answer which is not valid in my case:

The implementation of my program is this way:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct GLUquadric
    {
        int normals;
        bool textureCoords;
        int orientation;
        int drawStyle;

        public void Init(int norm, int draw, int orient, bool textCoor)
        {
            normals = norm;
            drawStyle = draw;
            orientation = orient;
            textureCoords = textCoor;
        }
    }
```

Use is:

```
            public static void DrawSphere(T Radius, Int32 Slices, Int32 Stacks, 
            GLU.QuadricDrawStyles Style, GLU.QuadricNormals Normal, Color color)
        {
            OpenGL.SetColor(color);
            GLU.GLUquadric quadric = new GLU.GLUquadric();
            quadric.Init((int)Normal, (int)Style, 0, false);
            GLU.Sphere(ref quadric, (dynamic)Radius, Slices, Stacks);
        }
```

Implementation is full OO, so every Sphere is isolated from static GL Function as `gluQuadricDrawStyle` and `gluQuadricNormals` so leaving struct empty is NOT valid since it will draw nothing.

Comment: The problem with this approach is, that you don't know the internal memory layout of GLUquadric. You found the structure definition of *some* GLU implementation, but you may very well end up on a system where the installed GLU implementation uses an entirely different struct layout and if that happens you're invoking C undefined behaviour which is **BAD** (caps-lock all bold bad). *Never do this!* If you do this you're entering a world of pain. Illustration of C code's attitude when invoking UB: https://imgur.com/ZlB9kHD

Comment: As I said, this is working and properties are the right ones.
I need no more calls to glu functions since the struct is *the correct one*
Sending this struct reference gives me the full control of the properties avoiding calling P/Invoke.

Comment: It only works by coincidence because the implementation of GLU on your system happens to use the same struct layout as the one which you found. But if you update your OS, or distribute your program you may end up on a system that uses a completely different internal struct layout and then *everything* breaks. Is this really so hard to understand for you? You're dealing with an *opaque* data type here. You're not just not supposed to know how it looks on the inside. It's actually forbidden to make any assumption.

Comment: The whole point of an opaque type is, that you must not make any assumptions about what's going on on the inside and only carry around a pointer or handle to something the library gave you. The next GLU implementation you come across may have a different layout or (that's something all my libraries that hand out opaque handles) check of the pointer passed to its functions is in the set of objects actually created with it; and if not throwing an error. **Your code is _not_ robust**. It just seems to work by happenstance.

Answer (score 1):

The bigger question is, if you actually want to use GLU at all. GLU has not been maintained for decades and didn't keep up with the development of the OpenGL API. GLU is not part of OpenGL proper, it's a companion library developed by SGI alongside OpenGL and published together with the OpenGL-1.1 specification. This first and latest version of GLU still assumes the presence of a fixed function pipeline and immediate drawing modes. Both have been removed from modern OpenGL.

> I need to create a struct so I can send it to gluNewQuadric.

Actually there's no need to know what's inside this struct. It's defined as a opaque pointer type. Think of it as a class instance handle to which you don't have the interface; you can still pass it into the module implementing the class and call global methods on it, but you can't look inside. From the C# perspective it's an unmanaged pointer to *something*.

**EDIT** a code example (that I hope is valid C#)

```
[DllImport("glu32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr gluNewQuadric();
[DllImport("glu32.dll")]
static extern void gluDeleteQuadric(IntPtr quadric);
[DllImport("glu32.dll")]
static extern void gluSphere(IntPtr quadric, double radius, int slices, int stacks);

IntPtr quadric = gluNewQuadric();
gluSphere(quadric, 1, 10, 10);
gluDeleteQuadric(quadric);
```

That being said if you accept these caveats I wonder if it wouldn't make more sense to port some GLU implementation over to .net/CLI so that it can be used natively from C#.

You can of course also access GLU through unmanaged interfaces. Now my personal experience with C# is little (I've got more experience with F#) and I never left the managed grounds doing unmanaged things. But from my understanding what you have to do there is just define an integer variable large enough to *hold* a native pointer (and if I'm not mistaken, there already should be such a integer type for holding unmanaged pointers) and use that for the `GLUQuadric*` type.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I already know it, but you could post it as a comment since this is not an answer to my question

Comment: @c_str: Obviously you didn't really read my answer. If you want to use the native GLU you don't need to know the struct definition. It's an opaque pointer. Technically speaking it behaves just like a handle. You call gluNewQuadric and it returns a pointer to "something" called a "GLUquadric" struct. But you're not supposed to look inside the struct; in fact the actual struct layout is undetermined and whatever definition you have found may be completely different to what your particular GLU installation uses. For what it's worth that opaque pointer is just a number in a pointer sized integer.

Comment: I read it, but it's not helping me, and it will NOT work since struct is null, reference will be null because I'm isolating OpenGL shapes. I'm not calling gluSetQuadricNormals nor gluSetQuadricDrawStyle.

What I did is isolated from those functions. If I leave struct empty, it will draw nothing. If I create struct, I can modify normals, drawstyle, orientation and texture isolated from static dll imported functions and it will draw.
Struct is necessary in my case.

Comment: @c_str: You create struct with `gluNewQuadric`. If I Googled it correctly: `IntPtr quadric = gluNewQuadric();` you use then `quadric` everywhere a quadric is required. Opaque pointer means you never touch the struct inside directly. You use functions from the library to allocate and modify the struct.

Comment: I'm not using Opaque pointers.
Every shape in my OpenGL context is treated as an object.
I'm not using `gluQuadricDrawStyle` or `gluQuadricNormal` to keep object oriented model in my program structure.

Comment: @c_str: I added a code example, that hopefully is valid C#. Just to make this clear: As a programmer you never see what's inside the GLUquadric struct. All you have is a pointer/handle that the GLU library gives you to refer to a GLUquadric object that you created with the `gluNewQuadric` function.

Comment: `gluNewQuadric ` returns a gluQuadric.
I still need to call `gluQuadricDrawStyle` and `gluQuadricNormal` to give Style and Normals to the sphere.

So your suggestion is:

Call `gluNewQuadric ` in P/Invoke,
Call `gluQuadricDrawStyle` in P/Invoke,
Call `gluQuadricNormal` in P/Invoke,

The issue: 3 calls every time the sphere is drawn instead of sending a defined struct every time the sphere is drawn.
As a programmer you should optimize the code and know what's going on inside the code, else you will just develop without caring about performance. I'm caring about performance since it's a 3D app.

Comment: @c_str: You can reuse the quadric. Make the calls to `gluNewQuadric`, `gluQuadricNormal` and `gluQuadricDrawStyle` once and then keep the opaque pointer around, reusing it for subsequent draw calls.

Comment: The frankness of this answer saved me a lot of wasted time on glu.. thanks OP